# How to find the maximum and sum of a row within a matrix

Tags: c, matrix

To the best of my knowledge what I have entered should be working properly, but I am new to C and am unable to come up with a reason as to why it isn't. Each function works fine separately but for some reason whilst together they produce weird errors.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

main()
{
   int m, n, c, d, sum, matrix[10][10], maximum;

   printf("Enter the number of rows and columns of matrix\n");
   scanf("%d%d",&m,&n);
   printf("Enter the elements of matrix\n");

   for( c = 0 ; c < m ; c++ )
   {
      for( d = 0 ; d < n ; d++ )
      {
         scanf("%d",&matrix[c][d]);
      }
   }

   maximum = matrix[0][0];

//Maximum
   for( c = 0 ; c < m ; c++ )
   {
      for( d = 0 ; d < n ; d++ )
      {
         if ( matrix[c][d] > maximum )
            maximum = matrix[c][d];
      }
   }
   //Sum
   for (c = 0; c < m; ++c)
   {
        for (d = 0; d < n; ++d)
        {
            sum = sum + matrix[c][d] ;
        }

        printf("Sum of the %d row is = %d\n", c, sum);
        sum = 0;

    }

    printf("Maximum element in matrix is %d\n", maximum);

   getch();
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Currently sum is not initialized, if you add `sum = 0;` directly after the `//Sum` comment but before the second set of loops does it fix any of your issues?

Answer (score 1):

You are operating addition operation on int sum before initializing it to 0. Initialize sum to 0 while declaring and that should fix your issue.